# Why NuGet does not install jQuery Validation folders?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I went on https://jqueryvalidation.org/ and downloaded the zip file, which comes with several folders, such `src/localization`, that contains message files for several languages.

Then, on my Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET MVC 4 Web project, I installed jQuery Validation via NuGet, with the following command:

`Install-Package jQuery.Validation -Version 1.16.0`

But it didn't add any folder, only some `.js` files. My `Scripts` folder looks like this:

```
bootstrap.js
bootstrap.min.js
Gruntfile.js
jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js
jquery-1.4.4.js
jquery-3.2.1.js
jquery-3.2.1.min.js
jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.min.js
modernizr-2.6.2.js
```

Does it fetch all available languages online? How do I set a language if I don't have any file to set on?

Comment: Why are you adding jQuery multiple times?  Why are you adding Bootstrap and jQuery Validate twice?  BTW - jQuery needs to be loaded **before** Bootstrap.

Comment: @Sparky I added only the version 3.2.1, other versions were added nuget. I add Bootstrap and JQuery Validate .min.js and .js, in case I need to read the code, wich is really hard having only .min version. I don't remember in wich order I added Bootstrap and jQuery, but at the _Layout page I render jQuery first.